# Is @page really supported by current browsers?

Tags: css, printing, princexml

I used to think that the only layout engine supports @page is PrinceXML, but recently I detected this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Try to print [this demo page](http://richstyle.org/demo-web.php) in different browsers and PrinceXML.

Do I miss something?

Comment: the demo page link you posted is dead

Comment: I'm sorry, it's working now.

Comment: in chrome it looks like it's working..

Comment: So what is the question? The doc you refer to say it's support in almost every browser in use today. Do you have any reason to doubt that, any particular problems? Or should we analyze the CSS and deduce a question ourselves? :o)

Comment: PrinceXML's output shows headers and footers defined by the attached CSS file, Chrome and Firefox don't.

Answer (score 0):

There was a long period in which Prince was way ahead of browsers in support of `@page` rules and other things that are generally useful for book generation, printing, etc. I do not believe browsers yet have good support for things like offset printing, archival PDF format selection, and lots of other features that are suited to print/book creation, but they are way closer than they used to be.